# How to construct help page for inherited classes in WCF

Tags: c#, json, wcf, documentation, known-types

I used `[KnownType] attribute` for inherited classes in my WCF webservice. My problem is that the help page on endpoint (.../WebServices/Gateway.svc/help/operations/GetMessages) shows just one of the inherited classes as  example.

it shows as below:

```
{
    "Code":"String content",
    "Messages":[{
        "__type":"PhotoMessage:#ApplicationGateway",
        "KeyboardButtons":[{
            "BackGroundColor":"String content",
            "Text":"String content"
        }],
        "Caption":"String content",
        "Url":"String content"
    }]
}
```

[the image of my WCF webservice help page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6S1yi.png)

But I want it to show as below(have an example for each inherited Class):

```
{
    "Code":"String content",
    "Messages":[{
        "__type":"PhotoMessage:#ApplicationGateway",
        "KeyboardButtons":[{
            "BackGroundColor":"String content",
            "Text":"String content"
        }],
        "Caption":"String content",
        "Url":"String content"
    }]
}
{
    "Code":"String content",
    "Messages":[{
        "__type":"TextMessage:#ApplicationGateway",
        "KeyboardButtons":[{
            "BackGroundColor":"String content",
            "Text":"String content"
        }],
        "Text":"String content"
    }]
}
```

Does anyone know a way to add this feature to WCF webservice help page?

my classes are as below:

**Message class :**

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(PhotoMessage))]
[KnownType(typeof(TextMessage))]
public abstract class Message
{
    [DataMember]
    public KeyboardButton[] KeyboardButtons { set; get; }
}
```

**TextMessage class :**

```
[DataContract]
public class TextMessage : Message
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Text { set; get; }
}
```

**PhotoMessage class :**

```
[DataContract]
public class PhotoMessage:Message
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Url { set; get; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Caption { set; get; }
}
```

And What My Endpoint Return is :

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(PhotoMessage))]
[KnownType(typeof(TextMessage))]
public class WebServiceOutputGetMessages
{
    [DataMember]
    public Message[] Messages { set; get; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Code { set; get; }
}
```